# Extract a line from a text file using grep?

Tags: bash, shell

I have a textfile called log.txt, and it logs the file name and the path it was gotten from. so something like this

```
2.txt
/home/test/etc/2.txt
```

basically the file name and its previous location. I want to use grep to grab the file directory save it as a variable and move the file back to its original location.

```
for var in "$@"
do
if grep "$var" log.txt
then
    # code if found
else
    # code if not found
fi
```

this just prints out to the console the 2.txt and its directory since the directory has 2.txt in it.

thanks.

Comment: What are the arguments `$@` you pass to the posted script?

Comment: Are you certain that 'log.txt' will not occur more than one in the entire file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe flip the logic to make it more efficient?

```
f=''
while read prev
do case "$prev" in
   */*) f="${prev##*/}"; continue;; # remember the name
     *) [[ -e "$f" ]] && mv "$f" "$prev";;
done < log.txt
```

That walks through all the files in the log and if they exist locally, move them back. Should be functionally the same without a `grep` per file.

If the name is always the same then why save it in the log at all?
If it is, then

```
while read prev
do f="${prev##*/}" # strip the path info
   [[ -e "$f" ]] && mv "$f" "$prev" 
done < <( grep / log.txt )
```

Comment: Looks like you changed the format in the OP. Are the filenames always the same after the move? The input file is a line with the falename bare, then another with the original path?

Answer (score 0):

Having the file names on the same line would significantly simplify your script. But maybe try something like

```
# Convert from command-line arguments to lines
printf '%s\n' "$@" |
# Pair up with entries in file
awk 'NR==FNR { f[$0]; next }
    FNR%2 { if ($0 in f) p=$0; else p=""; next }
    p { print "mv \"" p "\" \"" $0 "\"" }' - log.txt |
sh
```

Test it by replacing `sh` with `cat` and see what you get. If it looks correct, switch back.

Briefly, something similar could perhaps be pulled off with `printf '%s\n' "$@" | grep -A 1 -Fxf - log.txt` but you end up having to parse the output to pair up the output lines anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution:

```
for f in `grep -v "/" log.txt`; do 
    grep "/$f" log.txt | xargs -I{} cp $f {} 
done
```

Answer (score -1):

`grep -q`   (for "quiet") stops the output